# How to put a value into a Pointer column?

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm working with 'Parse.com' and I would like to store a value into a column in a Class that points to another Class.

For example:

```
$user = new ParseUser();
$user->set("username", "Batman");
$user->set("password", "darkknight"); 
$user->set("vehicle_ID", "UgTuNHEQEZ"); //pointer
```

Here, "vehicle_ID" is the name of the column. It's a pointer to the column id in the Class "Vehicle".

The error I get is that Parse expected the name of the Class I'm referring to. So, if I change the last line and do:

```
$user->set("Vehicle", "UgTuNHEQEZ");
```

The new user is created BUT the "vehicle_ID" is empty. Why is `vehicle_ID` not populated?

Comment: Sorry I think you may have to do a little more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double handicapped by not knowing php and discovering to my dismay that the parse.com API reference is a link to the github source, I did notice in the source a constructor function as follows:

```
public function __construct($className = null, $objectId = null,
    $isPointer = false
) {
...
```

This suggests:

```
$vehicle = new ParseObject("OtherClass", "UgTuNHEQEZ", true);
$user->set("vehicle_ID", $vehicle);
```

Comment: Thanks man, but it does not work. I tried something similar but I always get syntax errors. I don´t know why but it seems to need the name of the Class witch I´m pointing to as the first parameter.

Comment: Hmmm.  Sorry that wasn't it.  Please see edit.  If that's not it, we should wait and hope for a real PHP-Parse developer to answer.  (Again, remember to replace "OtherClass" double check that vehicle_ID is a pointer column (and consider renaming it).

Comment: YES! That did it! Do you think is there a shorthand (like the first example you showed me) to do this?

Comment: Good.  I don't see any evidence of a shorthand in the guide.  I did notice just now while skimming that the formulation `new ParseObject("Class", "objectId")` was used in a discussion of relations.  So thats a sign we're right, and maybe a sign that that's the most concise form.  Will edit my answer to remove the false-start.